# SSH: Use key-pair authentication, but if not present default to password

Tags: ssh, password, key-authentication

I am hoping to find a way to configure our systems so that it will work with ssh-key-pair authentication, but if not present, fail over to requiring a password, and fail login if incorrect password is provided.

We want the ssh-keys to be default.  I am aware that we can force password auth, but that kills key-pair auth.  Anyway to only force password if key-pair is not configured or fails?

WHY? (Requested clarification)

CIS9 5.3 Configure privilege escalation
CIS9 5.3.4  Ensure users must provide password for escalation (Automated)

So I apologize, with my thoughts being twisted into a pretzel, I was not clear.  This is ssh and sudo escalation.  If you force a password with sudo escalation in RHEL 9; it breaks the password less auth for SSH.

From our testers:

> It is not possible to sudo as its-user right after a new RHEL 9.x VM is provisioned.
> An issue is present in Section 5.3.4 - (Ensure users must provide password for escalation (Automated)| /etc/sudoers.d.
>
> This part of section 5.3.4 conflicts with our provisioning process. After some analysis, it is best to remove/comment the section, as its-user is automatically removed after 14 days. Other sudoers permissions come after joining Active Directory.
>
> When the role runs it forces its-user to use a password to sudo. By design, the temporary its-user account does not have a password, as ssh keys are used instead.

Comment: The `ssh` client uses ssh keys by default. Is it what you want? Or do you want the server to enforce the key usage if an `.ssh/authorized_keys` file is found?

Comment: SSH key-pairs by default, then fail to password if that is not working.  I know that seems like what most people are experiencing and then asking how to fix it.

Comment: We have a set of Ansible roles that is applying security policies based on CIS and our own ISO (Information Security Office) to brand new deployed RHEL 8/9 VMs.   When it is deployed we do not want to force password (what CIS recommends) as that breaks automation with Ansible down the road.

Comment: I've written up an answer but honestly it's not clear how you arrived at this question because it's completely default behaviour.  If you are not seeing this then you may need to [edit] your question to explain precisely what security policies Ansible is applying.

Comment: You said «how to fix it?». Could you explain further what is happening in your configuration, and what is expected to be different.

Answer (score 0):

After question edits, the context of the question has change the answer. You may be left with a question that would be better asked over on https://security.stackexchange.com/

The security requirement here is effectively discussing the `sudo` command. It's not actually about SSH at all.

The `sudo` command us used to allow a user gain extra privileges.  For example regular users cannot typically mount drives or modify most files in `/etc/`.  The `sudo` command can be used to grant access to become `root` and so have access to do much more.  Adding privileges in this way is called "privilege escalation".

So what this security requirement is telling you is that the `sudo` command must demand a user's password.

What you've run into here is a problem where your systems have a user (named `its-user`?) that can execute `sudo` without entering a password.  It's been setup this way because the user is used for automated setup of the virtual machine.  With no human at the terminal, asking for a password will just make things stop and wait forever.

---

Reading between the lines, this user needs to execute the sudo command as part of your Ansible scripts.

My first response would be to challenge if the Ansible scripts should be setup this way.  There is a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422263/453851) that maybe you can change your Ansible scripts to not need sudo. *I'm not an Ansible expert, so I'm not sure if `become` requires `sudo` or not.*

Next I would look to see if you can narrow down the precise uses of `sudo` in this early phase.  You might be able to modify `/etc/sudoers` to allow specific commands for this user without a password, rather than allowing it to execute anything it likes without a password.

Next look if you can do anything better to lock it down. Perhapse your Ansible Scripts could lock themselves out as the last action they perform.

If all else fails I'd ask if this a problem? Maybe / maybe not. That's more a security question.

If the user is only for automated use without human login then you might not care so much.  But maybe you do just to keep the auditors happy.